# passing student id to edit page

Tags: php, html, mysqli

im currently working on student admin page, i got a little problem displaying student data in edit page, to determine the student i use passing id when click edit.

my edit page query

```
<?php
  $user = $_GET["id"];
  $query = "SELECT *  FROM kuala_lumpur UNION ALL 
                SELECT *FROM eastern UNION ALL
                    SELECT *FROM northern UNION ALL
                        SELECT * FROM sabah UNION ALL
                            SELECT * FROM sarawak  
                         WHERE ID_NO = '$user'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die ('query die'); 
  $userget =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  ?>


<div class="thebox  thebox-more">
<form method="post">
  <table class="table tablo center-hr " border="0">
    <tr><th colspan="6"><h3>Student Information</h3></th>

    <tr class="text-right">
        <td><label>Name</label></td>
        <td colspan="5"><input type="text" name="NAME" value="<?php echo $userget['NAME']; ?>"></td>

    <tr class="text-right">
        <td><label>Student IC</label></td>
        <td colspan="2"> <input type="text" name="IC_NO" value="<?php echo $userget['IC_NO']; ?>"  ></td> 

        <td><label>Student ID</label></td>
        <td colspan="2"> <input type="text" name="ID_NO" value="<?php echo $userget['ID_NO']; ?>"></td> 
    </tr></i>
```

my list of student in table

```
    $th1 = 'Student ID';
    $th2 = 'Name';
    $th3 = 'Course';
    $th4 = 'Convocation Date';
    $th5 = 'Edit';

    $td1 = 'ID_NO';
    $td2 = 'NAME';
    $td3 = 'PROGRAM_CODE';
    $td4 = 'CONVO_DATE';
    $td5 = 'PROGRAM_DESC';

    <div class ="table tbody" >
        <table class="table table-hover bg-brand" data-toggle="table" >
        <?php
            if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {

    echo "<thead>
        <tr>
            <th class='text-center'>".$th1."</th>
            <th class='text-center'>".$th2."</th>
            <th class='text-center'>".$th3."</th>
            <th class='text-center'>".$th5."</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>";
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {   
    echo "<tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class='text-center'>".$row[$td1]."</td>
            <td>".$row[$td2]."</a><br>
            <b style='padding-left:7px;'><i>".$row[$td5]."</i></b></td>
            <td class='text-center'>".$row[$td4]."</td>
            <td><center><a href=\"info.php?id={$row[$td1]}\">X</a></center></td></tr>
        </tr>
    </tbody>";      
            } 
        }?>
</i>
```

the data that display is not change after i click other student im new to `UNION ALL` i got a feeling the problem in the query but i try change it many times but still no luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the where clause does apply only to the last query in your code. Also, prevent SQL injection attacks by making sure the user id is an integer.

```
     $user = intval($_GET["id"]);
      $query = "

                        SELECT * 
                        FROM kuala_lumpur 
                        WHERE ID_NO = '$user'
                    UNION ALL 
                        SELECT * 
                        FROM eastern 
                        WHERE ID_NO = '$user'
                    UNION ALL
                        SELECT * 
                        FROM northern 
                        WHERE ID_NO = '$user'
                    UNION ALL
                        SELECT * 
                        FROM sabah 
                        WHERE ID_NO = '$user'
                    UNION ALL
                        SELECT * 
                        FROM sarawak  
                        WHERE ID_NO = '$user'";
       $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die ('query die'); 
       $userget =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

When you include data from the database in the HTML input field, it is better to escape it:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($userget['NAME'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>
```

Is there any other issue that needs to be addressed?

Comment: omg haha didn't know its that simple this hunt me for days but u solve it in minute lol.... i got another question how to use update union? is it same as above? or a little bit different?

Comment: Well the database design with separate tables for each region is a bit awkward. It might help to include the region in the data, e.g.: `SELECT 'sarawak' as region, * FROM sarawak  WHERE ID_NO = '$user'` so you can use the region later when doing an update.